# Keeping popover active when moving mouse on it with Bootstrap 4.0 and Rails 5.1

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popover

I'm using Bootstrap 4.0 with my Rails 5.1 website. I made a popover for user details that trigger at mouse hover, it has website link in it.

```
<a data-toggle="popover" title="Mini profile" data-content="<%= post.user.location %><%= post.user.website %>">
     <%= post.user.fullname %>
</a>
```

So I need popover to stay on when I move mouse hover the popover itself, so that I can click website link in it. But currently it is disappearing as soon as I move my mouse out if the link. How can I keep it open?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'bottom',
        trigger : 'hover'
    });
});
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well I quickly created a prototype as below. You need to generate the HTML markup similar to below using Rails and include the JavaScript on your page.

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").each(function(i, obj) {
  $(this)
    .popover({
      html: true,
      trigger: "manual",
      content: function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        return $("#popover-content-" + id).html();
      }
    })
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
      var _this = this;
      $(this).popover("show");
      $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
        $(_this).popover("hide");
      });
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function() {
      var _this = this;
      setTimeout(function() {
        if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
          $(_this).popover("hide");
        }
      }, 300);
    });
});
```

```css
.container {padding:20px;}
.form-control {width:120px;}
.popover {max-width:400px;}

#popover-content-logout > * {
  background-color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap Popover HTML Example</h3>
  <a data-toggle="popover" title="Mini Profile" data-container="body" data-placement="right" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="margin:3px 0 0 0"></span> Hover Over Me</a>
  <div id="popover-content-info" class="hide">
    <strong>Pranav</strong><br/>
    <a href="https://pranavprakash.net">My Website</a>
  </div>
</div>
```